# External image not in same folder in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to add a picture to my *SWF* file as a `loadeMovie()` to a symbol or to my whole page. I can do that and I know a lot of ways but in all of them you have to put that image file beside your *SWF* in the same folder.

As I work with c# and I have to communicate with *SWF* is there any way to send a directory path of your picture to *SWF* to show that image?

That image can be *JPEG* or *BMP* or anything. There is no difference for me to work with *AS2* or *AS3*.

```
var mcHolder:MovieClip = createEmptyMovieClip("mcHolder", getNextHighestDepth());
var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
mcLoader.addListener(this);

mcLoader.loadClip("z.jpg", mcHolder);
```

and other simple code that worked:

```
loadMovie("z.jpg","dd");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider presenting some code to make the issue more clear.

Comment: i just want to know is it possible to load an image in swf by giving a directory of a file on my pc as string ? if yes. how?

Comment: Don't repeat the same thing in the comment. Update the question to be more clear. As I've mentioned - it is good to provide a relevant code sample.

Comment: alright.loadMovie("z.jpg","dd"); i tried this but it certainly image file needs to be beside swf

Comment: and i tried this: var mcHolder:MovieClip = createEmptyMovieClip("mcHolder", getNextHighestDepth());
var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
mcLoader.addListener(this);
mcHolder.height=5;
mcHolder.width=5;
mcLoader.loadClip("z.jpg", mcHolder);

Comment: but in second one too you need to put the image file beside it

Comment: By "updating the question" I meant editing it. Use the `edit` button and add the details there.

Comment: sorry. im new in so :D now i edit it

Comment: No problem. Consider also reading the short info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help) about asking questions.

Comment: Sorry for picking at you again, but now it's not clear what *doesn't* work. You ask a question and then say, "and other simple code that worked" - so what's the problem in this code? However, this question looks good now, thank you for your updates. My remark may come from the fact, that I'm not familiar with SWF loading from C#. One idea that comes to my mind - have you tried attaching some kind of `oninit` event from C# and putting the path there?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to provide a directory structure from the example you provided. Here is a quick sample:

```
<embed src="myFlashMovie.swf"
    quality="high"
    bgcolor="#ffffff"
    width="550"
    height="400"
    name="myFlashMovie"     
    FlashVars="directory=directory"
    align="middle"
    allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
    allowFullScreen="false"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"
/>
```

Now you should be able to get the 'directory' string and use it on your code:

```
var customDirectory:String = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.directory;
```

and finally the reveal:

```
mcLoader.loadClip(customDirectory+"/z.jpg", mcHolder);
```